# Memory Leak Using JSON-C

Tags: c, json, memory-management, memory-leaks, json-c

I am new to JSON-C, Please see my sample code and let me know of it will create any memory leak, if yes then how to free JSON-C object.

```
    struct json_object *new_obj         = NULL;
    new_obj = json_tokener_parse(strRawJSON);
    new_obj = json_object_object_get(new_obj, "FUU");
    if(NULL == new_obj){
        SYS_OUT("\nFUU not found in JSON");
        return NO;
    }
    new_obj = json_object_object_get(new_obj, "FOO"); // I m re-using new_obj, without free it?  
    if(NULL == new_obj){
        SYS_OUT("\nFOO not found in JSON");
        return NO;
    }
    // DO I need to clean new_obj, if yes then how ??
```

Do I need to clean new_obj, if yes then how. Can some one help to understand how to do memory management JSON-C.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A quick web search seems to indicate that JSON-C uses reference counting to manage `json_object` instances and the function used to "free" the instances is [json_object_put](http://oss.metaparadigm.com/json-c/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a15).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NO, We need to call json_object_put only once for root object as long as we are not explicitly allocating memory to json-object and this worked for me.....!!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I believe your code will leak memory.  The problem is that you are overwriting your new_obj pointer multiple times.  Your code should be something like this:

```
struct json_object *new_obj, *fuu_obj, *foo_obj;
new_obj = json_tokener_parse(strRawJSON);
fuu_obj = json_object_object_get(new_obj, "FUU");
if(NULL == new_obj){
    SYS_OUT("\nFUU not found in JSON");
    return NO;
}
foo_obj = json_object_object_get(new_obj, "FOO"); 
if(NULL == new_obj){
    SYS_OUT("\nFOO not found in JSON");
    return NO;
}
json_object_put(foo_obj);
json_object_put(fuu_obj);
json_object_put(new_obj);
```

Please let me know if this works for you.  If you want more help, json-c has a reference count mode which can give you more information about objects.  Let me know and I can elaborate on this more.

Comment: NO, We need to call json_object_put only once for root object as long as we are not explicitly allocating memory to json-object and this worked for me.....!!

Comment: Yes actually you are right.  You only need to call put one time for the root object!

Answer (score 2):

`json_tokener_parse()` will create an object which must be deleted.
in this case

`json_object_put(new_obj);`

is required.